# why don't TableView,TableCell appear?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

i'm making a chatApp so i'm trying to make a tableview showing profileimage and name but it isn't working now

i use Firebase Storage and Database for this App

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

this is the UserModel class that stores user's info extracting from Firebase

```
import UIKit

class UserModel: NSObject {
    @objc var userName : String!
    @objc var profileImageUrl : String!
    @objc var uid : String!
}
```

this is the PeopleViewController that shows people's information like peopleImage, name

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage


class PeopleViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


    var array : [UserModel] = []
    var tableview : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableview = UITableView()
        tableview?.delegate = self
        tableview?.dataSource = self
        tableview?.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        view.addSubview(tableview!)
        tableview?.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
            m.top.equalTo(view)
            m.bottom.left.right.equalTo(view)
        }


        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            self.array.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children{
                let fchild = child as! DataSnapshot
                let userModel = UserModel()

                UserModel.setValuesForKeys(fchild.value as! [String : Any])
                self.array.append(userModel)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview?.reloadData()
                }
        })

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview?.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let imageview = UIImageView()
        cell?.addSubview(imageview)
        imageview.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
            m.centerY.equalTo(cell!)
            m.left.equalTo(cell!).offset(10)
            m.height.width.equalTo(50)
        }



        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: array[indexPath.row].profileImageUrl!)!){ (data, response, err) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageview.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.frame.size.width/2
                imageview.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }.resume()


        let label = UILabel()
        cell?.addSubview(label)
        label.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
            m.centerY.equalTo(cell!)
            m.left.equalTo(imageview.snp.right).offset(20)
        }

        label.text = array[indexPath.row].userName

        return cell!
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController

        view?.destinationUid = self.array[indexPath.row].uid

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view!, animated: true)
    }
```

in Main.storyboard

i can't insert TableView on PeopleViewController directly

so why don't TableView appear on PeopleViewController while Runnig?

Comment: Try setting the tableView's frame to `tableview = UITableView(frame: .zero)` and also make sure `tableview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is set before your constraint code. Also tableview is not an optional so there is no need to include the `?` after the variable `tableview`.

Comment: You don't need this `DispatchQueue.main.async {` as UI calls in Firebase closures are performed on the main thread. Also naming vars the same thing as a class name can be very confusing 'UserModel.setValuesForKeys(fch'. How about just naming the var 'user' `let user = UserModel()`. The Firebase portion of the code actually works once the variable names are corrected. Did you test to see if your array was being populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give the frame for your UITableView, Please try below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableview = UITableView(frame: view.frame) // Or your desired frame
        // Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOUR TABLEVIEW WORKING FINE ..PLZ CHECK YOUR FIRBASE API RESPONCE

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i think you miss register your cell with table
here is solution of your code.

```
let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 500)

tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```

try this